# Permutation problem involving item order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

A professor writes 35 true/false discrete mathematics questions. The answer to 14 of these are true.  How many different answer keys are possible

- a) if the questions can be in any order?
- b) if every true statement is immediately followed by a false statement?

For the part a), I know it is simply ${35 \choose 14}$. I am having trouble with part b), where if every true statement is followed by false.

Comment: Pair the $TF$ together. So you will have $14$ such pairs $\ldots (TF) \ldots (TF) \ldots (TF) \ldots$ and now fill up the $7$ remaining $F'$s

Answer (score 0):

Pair every true with its following false and make a list of the $7$ false answers and the $14$ true/false answers

Comment: Would it be C(28,7)?

Comment: @AyeNayMyoMyint $14+7=28$?

Comment: Since 1 true 1 false, wouldn't it be 2*14?

Comment: No, it is just like part a.  We are given the number of items, $21$, and the number that are pure false, $7$, so there are $21 \choose 7$